# Clear inputs when the tab of Liferay:ui changes

Tags: jsp, liferay

I´m coding a portlet with some search utilities for a portal using Liferay Portal 6.0, but I´ve encountered a problem. I have the following code in jsp:

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
        names="articles,book chapters,books"
        refresh="<%= false %>"
        param="tab" 
        url="<someURL>"
        value="<%=tab%>"
    >
<liferay-ui:section>
  ...
  <form:input id="articleTitle" path="articleTitle"/>
  ...
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
  ...
  <form:input id="chapterTitle" path="chapterTitle"/>
  ...
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
  ...
  <form:input id="bookTitle" path="bookTitle"/>
  ...
</liferay-ui:section>
```

I need to clear the inputs´s content located inside the sections in real time when the user changes the tab, but I haven´t found the way to do it since i don´t know what event could be referred to to launch the proper script to do so.

Any help?

EDIT: the script I use to clear the input is this:

```
function clearInputs(){
    $("#articleTitle").val('');
    $("#chapterTitle").val('');
    $("#bookTitle").val('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `onClick` attribute in `liferay-ui:tabs` like that

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
    names="articles,book chapters,books"
    refresh="<%= false %>"
    param="tab" 
    url="<someURL>"
    value="<%=tab%>"
    onClick="alert(1)" //or your function
>
```

More informations [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-liferay-ui-tabs-and-sections).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You´re right, but when the script is executed (through putting onClick="clearInputs()" in tabs tag), it does not clear the inputs. Maybe there´s something wrong with the script but I can´t find the error. I have added to the question the script mentioned, so could you check it, please? :S

Comment: All right, I got it!, just had to change the script. I´ve edited to put the correct one. Thanks, pal :-)